# Map is not showing in OPEN STREET MAP

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to show the Map with Marker. I have add the following libraries in lib folder of my project:

1. **osmdroid-android-3.8.0.jar**
2. **slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar**

But only Marker shows and Map is not showing..

My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  private MapView myOpenMapView;
 private MapController myMapController;

 ArrayList<OverlayItem> anotherOverlayItemArray;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



     myOpenMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
        myOpenMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myMapController = myOpenMapView.getController();
        myMapController.setZoom(2);

        //--- Create Another Overlay for multi marker
        anotherOverlayItemArray = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
          "0, 0", "0, 0", new GeoPoint(0, 0)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
          "US", "US", new GeoPoint(38.883333, -77.016667)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
          "China", "China", new GeoPoint(39.916667, 116.383333)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
          "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", new GeoPoint(51.5, -0.116667)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
          "Germany", "Germany", new GeoPoint(52.516667, 13.383333)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
          "Korea", "Korea", new GeoPoint(38.316667, 127.233333)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
          "India", "India", new GeoPoint(28.613333, 77.208333)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
          "Russia", "Russia", new GeoPoint(55.75, 37.616667)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
          "France", "France", new GeoPoint(48.856667, 2.350833)));
        anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem(
          "Canada", "Canada", new GeoPoint(45.4, -75.666667)));

        ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> anotherItemizedIconOverlay 
         = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(
           this, anotherOverlayItemArray, null);
        myOpenMapView.getOverlays().add(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
        //---

        //Add Scale Bar
        ScaleBarOverlay myScaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(this);
        myOpenMapView.getOverlays().add(myScaleBarOverlay);
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you using such an old version?

Comment: @spy My client need me to draw a route path between two points, is it possible? please help me in this regard

Comment: yes, see osmbonuspack

Comment: @spy Brother, can you please give me any link or source code or tutorial for that, please i am need of it

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution. I just add the following line and it  is now showing the map

```
myOpenMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
```